# Parsec debugging

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I've been working with parsec and I have trouble debugging my code. For example, I can set a breakpoint in ghci, but I'm not sure how to see how much of the input has been consumed, or things like that.

Are there tools / guidelines to help with debugging parsec code?

Comment: When you run a parser - it should return an `Either ParseError a` - printing the ParseError will show you the source position and any error messages. Having your sample input in a text editor is probably the easiest way to see where the source position corresponds to, although you could write your own error throwing function to capture the rest-of-input and print its initial content  (`getInput` returns the remaining input).

Answer (score 9):

[This](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Debugging) page might help.

`Debug.trace` is your friend, it allows you to essentially do some `printf` debugging. It evaluates and prints its first argument and then returns its second. So if you have something like

```
foo :: Show a => a -> a
foo = bar . quux
```

You can debug the 'value' of foo's parameter by changing `foo` to the following:

```
import Debug.Trace(trace)

foo :: Show a => a -> a
foo x = bar $ quux $ trace ("x is: " ++ show x) x
```

foo will now work the same way as it did before, but when you call `foo 1` it will now print `x is: 1` to stderr when evaluated.

For more in-depth debugging, you'll want to use GHCI's debugging commands. Specifically, it sounds like you're looking for the `:force` command, which forces the evaluation of a variable and prints it out. (The alternative is the `:print` command, which prints as much of the variable as has been evaluated, without evaluating any more.)

Note that `:force` is more helpful in figuring out the contents of a variable, but may also change the semantics of your program (if your program depends upon laziness).

A general GHCI debugging workflow looks something like this:

- Use `:break` to set breakpoints
- Use `:list` and `:show context` to check where you are in the code
- Use `:show bindings` to check the variable bindings
- Try using `:print` to see what's currently bound
- Use `:force` if necessary to check your bindings

If you're trying to debug an infinite loop, it also helps to use

- `:set -fbreak-on-error`
- `:trace myLoopingFunc x y`

Then you can hit `Ctrl-C` during the loop and use `:history` to see what's looping.

Answer (score 5):

You might be able to use [the `<?>` operator](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.1.2/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Prim.html#v%3a-60--63--62-) in Text.Parsec.Prim to make better error messages for you and your users.  There are some [examples](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-parsec.html) in Real World Haskell.  If your parser has good sub-parts then you could setup a few simple tests (or use [HUnit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HUnit)) to ensure they work separately as expected.

Comment: Yeah, I guess liberally sprinkling `<?>` is probably the best I could do. Was hoping that there would be tools specifically designed to debug parsec though.

Answer (score 2):

Another useful trick:

`_ <- many anyChar >>= fail` this will generate an error (`Left`) of:

```
unexpected end of input
the remaining 'string'
```

---

I think the `parserTrace` and `parserTraced` functions mentioned here http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.13.0/docs/Text-Parsec-Combinator.html#g:1 do something similar to the above.